# Unable to delete files in an Django API call in Azure webapp

Tags: django, python-2.7, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to programatically delete a directory that I created in an API call to Django Server. But I am getting errors. So far, I have tried 2 approches -

```
def del_tree(dirpath):
    os.chmod(dirpath, stat.S_IWUSR)
    os.remove(dirpath)
```

When this function is called it throws error at `os.remove` line saying `Access is denied`.

Other approch was to use just `shutil.rmtree`. 
This one gave an error saying `File is being used by another process.`

Any idea how to fix this?